# about aligning the xlabel to center of the axis in matlab 3D figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting some 3D data in matlab and trying to rotate the xlabel such that it orients the same direction as the xaxis. I fix the view for the current 3D figure to some angle and with trail and error I found the correct angle to rotate the label.

```
view(al, ae);  % where al and ae is the parameter for the view I want
theta = 52;    % this angle is obtained by trail and error
xlabel('label at some angle', 'rot', theta)
```

Now the label oriented in the right direction but I found that it is no longer stay in the center of the corresponding axis, i.e. the center of the label no longer line up with the center of the x-axis. Is that any way to align them again?

Actually, I try something like [enter link description here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27450-align-axes-labels-in-3d-plot/content/axesLabelsAlign3D.m), but it doesn't work very well for the view. By following the idea in that link, I try something like

```
xf = 1.2*min(get(gca, 'xlim'));   % in my case zero is the middle or the xlim
yf = 1.2*min(get(gca, 'ylim'));   % in my case zero is the middle or the ylim
set(get(gca,'XLabel'),'Position', [0, yf, zf]);
set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'Position', [xf, 0, zf]);
set(get(gca,'xlabel'),'rot',thetax);
set(get(gca,'ylabel'),'rot',thetay);
set(get(gca,'zlabel'),'rot',thetaz);
```

So with above code, I set the position of the label to somewhere close to the center of the corresponding axis before rotation. If the label has only one character, then it works. But if the label is long, then it will have the first character aligned with the center of the axis instead. The reason is I didn't taking the length of the label into account. I know I should but the problem is how much should I offset the label from the center of the axis? I only know the size of the font and total number of characters of the label, how do I found out the actual length of the label? Thanks.